# refresh_token method in DocuSign SDK?

Tags: docusignapi

Using refresh token, you can get a new access token. https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant#

Couldn't find an API in SDK to renew the access token using refresh token. Please let me know if there is some API available and I wasn't able to find it in SDK or if there is some sample code available for it.

Answer (score 1):

I was recently working on a project where I needed to obtain an access token using a refresh token and did not find a suitable method in the sdk. So, as Larry K suggests, I made a POST request using the [superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent) library.The code looks like this :

```
const refreshToken = <yourRefreshToken>;
const clientString = clientId + ":" + clientSecret,  
postData = {      
  "grant_type": "refresh_token",      
  "refresh_token": refreshToken, },  
headers= {      
  "Authorization": "Basic " + (new 
       Buffer(clientString).toString('base64')),    
 },  
authReq = superagent.post( dsConfig.dsOauthServer +    
                      "/oauth/token")      
          .send(postData)
          .set(headers)      
          .type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

I wrote an [article](https://medium.com/@sanjuctab/using-a-refresh-token-to-obtain-an-access-token-from-docusign-3c297eb51886) on this which might help.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for generating new access token from refresh token:

```
    POST <YOUR_TOKEN_URI>
    Authorization: Basic <BASE64(‘YOUR_INTEGRATION_KEY: YOUR_SECRET_KEY’)>
    grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN
```

For the developer environment, the token URI is:
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token
For the production platform, the token URI is:
https://account.docusign.com/oauth/token

The base64 value for Authorization can be generated in a JavaScript console with the following method call:
btoa('Integration Key : Secret Key')

This can be done in Google Chrome -> More Tools -> Developer Tools -> Console -> type ‘btoa (‘Integration Key : Secret Key’) and press Enter
Or in google Chrome, Ctrl + Shift + I -> Console

Detailed information [here](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token#using-refresh-tokens).

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth Authorization Code Grant flow is quite standardized. Your favorite Authorization Code Grant library for your software stack (independent of DocuSign) can be used.

If you can't find a library you like, then you can make the POST request yourself using an HTTP request library.

Note that the other OAuth Authorization Code Grant support methods that are today available in some of the DocuSign SDKs will be deprecated in the future. It is better to use a stack-specific OAuth library that will automatically handle the redirect, proper use of the state parameter and other aspects of the Auth Code Grant flow.